# TypeForm WebHook пустое тело $_request

Tags: php, json

Подключил обработчик для получения вебхука с typeform.com
Запрос уходит в формате JSON, в `$_request`, `$_post`, `php://input` - пусто.
Что я делаю не так? Не могу получить массив JSON с данными 
Задавал header - `application/json`, `text/plain` `charset utf8`.
Код логирования входящего `json`:

```
<?php

header("Content-type:text/plain; charset=UTF-8");

function writeToLog($data, $title = '') {
 $log = "\n------------------------\n";
 $log .= date("Y.m.d G:i:s") . "\n";
 $log .= (strlen($title) > 0 ? $title : 'DEBUG') . "\n";
 $log .= print_r($data, 1);
 $log .= "\n------------------------\n";
 file_put_contents(getcwd() . '/hook.log', $log, FILE_APPEND);
} 


$json = @file_get_contents("php://input");
writeToLog($json, 'json');
writeToLog(json_decode($json, true), 'json decode');    
writeToLog($_REQUEST, '$_REQUEST');
writeToLog($_POST, '$_POST');

?>
```

Comment: А заголовок зачем задавать ?
И без него прекрасно запишется в файл.

Comment: Мне кажется у вас пустота , ничего не передается раз не записывается.
Попробует вывести на экран $_REQUEST и понять почему не передается а не записывается.

Comment: другие вебхуки получаю прекрасно в REQUEST и php-input, даже без заголовка. вот именно с typeform.com проблема =*(